# how to build gps signal receiver and transmitter in GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Can anyone guide me to accomplish my project?

That project consists of building  GPS receiver and transmitter using CDMA.

I have found gr-cdma in git but I don't know how to configure it. There are a lot of errors in it.

Comment: Hi Santa, your question is a bit too broad. Building a working GPS receiver is a big project, and your question would need an answer that is about as thick as a solid textbook on digital communications. The fact that you're trying to use gr-cdma to achieve that doesn't inspire too much confidence that you know the basics of GPS signaling. Anyway, there's existing GNSS receivers that work on a fork of GNU Radio, so maybe you simply want to use that? Also, if you haven't read http://tutorials.gnuradio.org

Comment: Dear @555, please don't just capitalize/change project name spellings as you think is right. The Project name is "GNU Radio", **not** "GNURADIO", and the out-of-tree module is called "gr-cdma", **not** "gr-CDMA" (and yes, that matters in a lot of places). Since your edit did more harm than good, I had to revert it. If improving grammar of questions, please make sure not to change questions.

Comment: Santa, also, it's unlikely there are a lot of errors in gr-cdma. It is likely that you're not using it correctly, or with incompatible software, or so. In any case, this question is too broad, underdefined, lacks explanation, errors, attempts, and thus can't be salvaged if you don't fundamentally improve it, please!

Comment: sorry, @SantaMarley I will be more careful